# Is Display Stream Compression Possible with Nvidia on linux now?

Tags: linux, drivers, nvidia

I've been impatiently waiting for DSC on linux for the better part of half a year as the final straw so that I can make the switch to linux as my daily driver. Back in May, I believe it was, NVIDIA made their GPU Kernel module open source, and I was hopeful that this would bring DSC to linux in the near future, yet I've heard nothing of it since then.

If anyone has information on whether or not DSC is possible using the current open source kernel module by NVIDIA, it would be appreciated. I am also curious if it would even be possible to implement DSC using just the kernel module, as from my understanding, there is still a great deal that nvidia has not made open source.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment DSC is not supported by Nvidia drivers (proprietary or open source) on Linux. I have been told it should be implemented in proprietary drivers 530.xx (no ETA so far): https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/discussions/238

PS: don't expect to see this feature in open source drivers any time soon, if ever. For Nvidia, proprietary is without a doubt the way to go.